# TCPDF - printing table from mysql showing repeated first row

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I am new to TCPDF. The small problem that I am facing is that all output data is displaying the same row. I mean the first record is repeated the number of times the total data(rows) exist in the database. Here is my code

```
$tbl_header = '<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
tr {
    padding: 3px 0;
}

th {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
}
</style>
<table id="gallerytab" width="600" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" border="0">
<tr>
        <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Products Title</font></th>
        <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Specs</font></th>
        <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Price</font></th>
        <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Products Image</font></th>
      </tr>';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

while ($row_Pro_Record = mysql_fetch_assoc($Pro_Record)) {
$tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$p_title.'</td>
        <td>'.$p_size.'</td>
        <td>'.$p_price.'</td>
        <td><img width="120"src="http://localhost/product/images/'.$c_name.'/'.$p_image.'.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
';
}
// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```

It could be a small stupid detail that I am missing as my php/mysql skills aren't that great. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is `$p_title` coming from ? `$row_Pro_Record` is the variable that contains your row data. So inside you table you should have something like

```
<td>'.$row_Pro_Record['title'].'</td>
```

where `title` is the name of the column, instead of

```
<td>'.$p_title.'</td>
```

have a read of the [mysql_fetch_assoc docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) it shows a nice example of looping over results :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Comment: Hi @ManseUK $p_title = $row_Pro_Record['product_title']; which I have declared earlier. The thing is that the record are showing properly in a normal php page but shows only the first repeated records when generating the pdf :/ I am stuck

Comment: @JunaidHassan include your full code - what you have above doesnt work - the loop doesnt actually loop anything - as the variables inside the loop remain static ...

Comment: thank you for your comments so far. Here is my full code
http://pastebin.com/BJ3UPFE5

Comment: @JunaidHassan you need to do exactly as I said in my question - you are not using the `$row_Pro_record` variable which changes each time the while loop is looped ... read the doc linked in my answer

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK, I got it! You were right the values that I was passing were static and when I used $row_Pro_Record['title'] it is displaying all the records. Much appreciated, I need to work on my php/mysql skills lol.